# Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/database/DataSource.xml]

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

Im trying to create an application that access a sql server database using Spring, Maven and Hibernate. When i try to run the application im getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/database/DataSource.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName'
```

Here are my classes

DataSoucre.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean 
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>/properties/database.properties</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" 
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="dataSource"/>
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
</property>

<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
    <value>com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Customer</value>
</list>
</property>

</bean>
</beans>
```

And database.properties

```
database.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Customer
database.username=*****
database.password=*****
```

(I have blocked the username and passwords just for here), i also have a BeanLocation.xml as well but shouldnt really need to post that up.

Does anyone know how to solve this, its driving me crazy!
Thanks

Comment: I think that problem is in your property file location. Do you have in classpath root folder properties and inside database.properties?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of `${jdbc.driverClassName}` in your XML, use `${database.driverClassName}`, ie the name of the property used in your `database.properties` file.

Comment: perfect, that did the trick...i would mark it up but not enough rep to do that yet :/ thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you need to ensure that the root location of the config files is accessible under classpath and then, add the relative path of your property file eg.
classpath:properties/database.properties

In my case, an additinal issue was an additonal '"' present by mistake that was leading to this error. Hope this helps.